# When I click Onback button Alert dialog and Progress dialog closed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my android App I showed alert dialog. When i click OnBack button that alert dialog was cancelled.My problem is when user click that onBack buton.I have to show that dialog.how can handle this. Thanks in advance.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder( HomeScreenActivity.this);
alertbox.setMessage("Please select a Favorite Business"); 
alertbox.setNeutralButton("Nearby", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
   { 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { } }) 
    .setNegativeButton("Search",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
       { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { } }); 
alertbox.show();
```

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
      // your code.
    dialog.setCancellable(false);
  }

Comment: Do you want to prevent from being closed on back pressed??

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
          HomeScreenActivity.this);
         
        alertbox.setMessage("Please select a Favorite Business");
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Nearby",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            
           }

           
          })
         .setNegativeButton("Search",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        
          

         }
        });
        alertbox.show();

Comment: check my answer, just set it while creating AlertDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It won't dismiss the dialog `onBackPress`

```
alertbox.setCancelable (false)
```

Sets whether this dialog is [`Cancelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29) with the `BACK key.`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder( HomeScreenActivity.this);
  alertbox.setMessage(""Please select a Favorite Business")
        .setCancelable(false)
         .setNuetralButton("Nearby", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


             }
         })
         .setNegativeButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

             }
         });
 alertbox.create();
 alertbox.show();

        }         
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You needed something like this:

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
@Override
                    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                            KeyEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }});
```